# Indentation after for instruction in xcode doesn't work

Tags: c++, xcode, for-loop, indentation

I've been using xcode for some months and this has never happened before, i'm not sure whether i pressed something i shouldn't have or meddled with the settings. Basically i write something like `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)` and press enter, and the cursor is on the next line above the instruction, so there's no visual subordination of what I'm about to write next.

If i press the tab key before writing a new instruction below and then write for instance `cout<<n-i<<endl;`, the moment I press `;` , the entire thing is moved in the same column(if that makes sense) again. This doesn't happen with other instructions like while or if. Help?

[image: 1]

Comment: Speaking of indentation: Can we have some paragraphs here?

Comment: probably a syntax error elsewhere in the file causing xcode confusion

Answer (score 0):

Normally indentation occurs when you *open a block*, as in type `{`. If you're using a blockless `if` then the code editor has to figure out after the fact what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem, but here are a few tips :

To format a selection in the editor

> **Main menu : Editor > Structure > Re-indent** ( or **^I** )

To remove the automatic formatting when pressing `;`

> **User Preferences : Text Editing > Automatic indent for** : Uncheck the **“;”** box